# VMPlayer doesn't have option LAN Segment

Tags: linux, networking, vmware-workstation

I got the VMware Workstation 15.0.3 Player doesn't have an option for either LAN Segmentation or an Custom (mostly) option for the Network Adapter Settings.

I got never an LAN Segmentation setting for any Virtual OS (i got multiple distros of linux and an Win 2016 Server). I just got the Custom for my Fedora Workstation.

I personally use Linux Mint 19.1. Does anybody got an idea how i can get those selections? I would really need them? Or does anybody know an workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The UI to configure them is not enabled in VMware (Workstation) Player.  You will need VMware Workstation Pro.

Comment: no this didnt work as well.

Comment: @Stefanxyz Could you elaborate?  What didn't work?  Do you mean that VMware Workstation Pro didn't have UI to configure LAN segments?  Or do you mean that you configured LAN segments with it but that they the VMs couldn't communicate with each other?  Or something else?

Comment: okay well the vmplayer didnt work but the vmware stuff did work tho.